# xamarin.Android C# - IFileNameFilter class implementation issues

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my file explorer app,i'm trying to display only xml files within any folders present.So each time we open a folder,i would only like to show xml files.I have looked through this site and the internet and there's plenty of examples but haven't found one in C#.I've also tried to modify other examples to my needs but i'm stuck implementing the IFileNameFilter class.Does anyone know how to do this?I tried to implement it but keep getting build errors.

In my code below,I have a ListFragment class which displays the files:

```
public override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {

        try{

        var fileSystemInfo = _adapter.GetItem(position);


        if (fileSystemInfo.IsFile())
        {
            // Do something with the file.  In this case we just pop some toast.
            Log.Verbose("FileListFragment", "The file {0} was clicked.", fileSystemInfo.FullName);
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "You selected file " + fileSystemInfo.FullName, ToastLength.Short).Show();

            OnFileClick (fileSystemInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            // Dig into this directory, and display it's contents

                RefreshFilesList(fileSystemInfo.FullName);
        }

        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.Error (TAG,e.ToString());

        }

        base.OnListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


    }

public void RefreshFilesList(string directory)
    {

        //GenericExtFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(extension);

        IList<FileSystemInfo> visibleThings = new List<FileSystemInfo>();

        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

        try
        {
            foreach (var item in dir.GetFileSystemInfos().Where(item => item.IsVisible()))
            {

                visibleThings.Add(item);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("FileListFragment", "Couldn't access the directory " + _directory.FullName + "; " + ex);
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Problem retrieving contents of " + directory, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return;
        }

        _directory = dir;

        _adapter.AddDirectoryContents(visibleThings);

        // If we don't do this, then the ListView will not update itself when the data set 
        // in the adapter changes. It will appear to the user that nothing has happened.
        ListView.RefreshDrawableState();

        Log.Verbose("FileListFragment", "Displaying the contents of directory {0}.", directory);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this with a much simplified solution.I didn't use the IFileNameFilter after all.Inside the RefreshFilesList method above,i made the following change:

```
foreach (var item in dir.GetFileSystemInfos().Where(item => item.IsVisible()))
            {
                if(item.IsDirectory())
                {

                    visibleThings.Add(item);

                }else if(item.IsFile())
                {

                    bool isXmlFile = item.Extension.ToLower().EndsWith("xml");
                    if(isXmlFile)
                    {
                    visibleThings.Add(item);
                    }

                }
            }
```

This now shows all folders and any xml files present.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to create IFilenameFilter that will filter XML files.

```
public class XmlFileFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IFilenameFilter
{
    public bool Accept(File dir, string filename)
    {
        return filename.ToLower().EndsWith(".xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for your answer but perhaps i ought to have been more specific.The snippet you've added here wasn't really the part i'm struggling with.The part i'm having a bit of trouble implementing is now how to use this class XmlFileFilter  in my code above.I think i need to use it in the method RefreshFilesList where i'm adding items to the visibleThings list.I've tried a couple of things like, adding an if statement inside the foreach loop which checks for the extension before adding it to the loop but that doesn't work properly.It doesn't add directories.